# Is there a simple way to copy a folder with its contents but without subfolders?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a application which is based around backing up data. I would like to add a option to copy a folder with its contents while ignoring the subfolders only.

I use `TDirectory.Copy('C:\folder','C:\folder2');` to copy folders but that has no additional data requested other than the directory to copy and where to copy.

So, Is there a simple way to achieve this?

A function that can be called would work too.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but maybe [`IFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) with the [`FOF_FILESONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-setoperationflags) flag?

Comment: So ... it's not perfect but you could make something like this :

''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect, but you could make your own routine based on this :

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aSourceDir : String;
  aDestDir   : String;
  aFileList  : TStringDynArray;
  iFile      : Integer;
  aSourceFileName : String;
  aDestFileName   : String;
begin
  aSourceDir := 'C:\DEV\GitRepositories\TestProjects\WithStatementSample\';
  aDestDir   := 'C:\DEV\GitRepositories\TestProjects\WithStatementSample2\';

  aFileList := TDirectory.GetFiles( aSourceDir );

  if not ( TDirectory.Exists( aDestDir ) ) and
         ( Length( aFileList ) > 0 ) then
  begin
    TDirectory.CreateDirectory( aDestDir );
  end;

  for iFile := 0 to Pred( Length( aFileList ) ) do
  begin
    aSourceFileName := aFileList[ iFile ];
    aDestFileName   := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter( aDestDir ) +
                       ExtractFileName( aFileList[ iFile ] );

    TFile.Copy( aSourceFileName, aDestFileName );
  end;
end;
```

This will simply loop over every file found in the Source directory and copy it to the destination directory. It will not copy folders, nor copy contents of the folders.

Again, it's not 100% fool/bullet proof though, so you will have to adapt it to your needs if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
Dec.26,2022 Update... The example code I submitted used literal values which
actually worked but not for my application. so...the problem with vars was
PAnsiChar not managing strings, so... (rather verbose code)... sSCBHostPath :=
gsAppPath + 'SCBHosts\'; sDirName := 'SCBHost' +
Trim(absqMyGuests.FieldByName('Guest_Name').AsString); sNewHostAppPath :=
sSCBHostPath + sDirName; sPCharString := 'XCopy ' + sAppDeploymentPath + ' ' +
sNewHostAppPath + ' /E /H /C /I'; cPChar {PAnsiChar type} :=
StringToPAnsiChar(sPCharString); //to reader, function code follows TRY
WinExec(cPChar,SW_SHOWNORMAL); EXCEPT ON E:EXCEPTION DO messagedlg('Exception:
' + e.Message,mterror,[mbok],0); END; // This function converts a string to a
PAnsiChar // If the output is not the same, an exception is raised // Author:
nogabel@hotmail.com function
TfInternetServersAndClients.StringToPAnsiChar(stringVar : string) : PAnsiChar;
Var AnsString : AnsiString; InternalError : Boolean; begin InternalError :=
false; Result := ''; try if stringVar <> '' Then begin AnsString :=
AnsiString(StringVar); Result := PAnsiChar(PAnsiString(AnsString)); end;
Except InternalError := true; end; if InternalError or (String(Result) <>
stringVar) then begin Raise Exception.Create('Conversion from string to
PAnsiChar failed!'); end; end; Dec.25,2022 Delphi XE2 Pro...
```

This opens `Command.com` and copies an entire folder and its subfolders and all files to a different drive, then disappears.

`WinExec(PAnsiChar('XCopy C:\Dir1 E:\Dir1 /E /H /C /I'),SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Next.
This opens Command.com and copies an entire folder and its subfolders and all files to an existing folder on the same drive named `C:\NewDir`.  The resulting `C:\NewDir` will contain a folder named Dir1 with all of its subfolders and files.

`WinExec(PAnsiChar('XCopy C:\Dir1 C:\NewDir /E /H /C /I'),SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: The solution will be work for Desktop platforms.
Please be noticed that Android was not support AnsiString type in Delphi 11.
The code might be work in Win32/Win64, but not work in Android.